# Method of Undetermined Coefficients (Vandermonde) on data points?

Tags: interpolation

I know how to interpolate using Vandermonde and obtain p(x) if the data points are given as something like `p(-1)=1  p(0)=0  p(1)=1`

But what if derivatives, p'(x) are given as data points additionally?

example data points: `p(-1)=1  p'(-1)=2  p(0)=0  p'(0)=2  p''(0)=3`

Honestly no idea how to do this

Comment: Why not adding them to your linear system of equations?

Comment: so do I form p(x) p'(x) p''(x) from give points and then solve the system?

Comment: Exactly. The matrix of the system may not be invertible like Vandermonde matrix, however it gives you the solutions.